# struct with enum compilation error based on position

Tags: c++, struct, enums

This:

```
enum Id {
    START,
    INDENT
};

struct State {
    int line;
    int column;
    Id id;
};

...

lexer::State state = {0};
```

compiles.

But if I put `Id id` as the first element of the struct, it stops. Can someone explain to me briefly why these two structs are treated differently.

Comment: Any reason not to use the C++ `lexer::State state = {};` initialization instead of that C style struct initialization?

Comment: Yep, will use that now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error because constant zero of type `int` is not compatible with the initial field `id` of type `Id`, unless

1) You add a cast, like this

```
lexer::State state = {static_cast<Id>(0)};
```

2) or use `START` in place of zero, like this

```
lexer::State state = {START};
```

3) or drop zero to value-initialize the whole `struct` (recommended):

```
lexer::State state = {};
```

Comment: @Quentin This works from `enum` to `int`, but `int` to `enum` doesn't work ([link to ideone](https://ideone.com/gaoIiP)).

Comment: Wow, did I drop the ball on that one. I haven't used plain `enum`s in a long time...

Comment: Oh, so lexer::State state = {0} means initialize the struct and specifically initialize the first field to 0? And any field that is omitted gets initialized to the default value?

Comment: @gruszczy Correct, values inside `{...}` in `struct`'s initializer are used to initialize `struct` members in the order that they appear in the declaration. Omitted fields get default-initialized.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `s/default/value/`. Default initialization of fundamental types performs nothing at all, while value-initialization sets them to a suitable "zero".